# Is it possible to make a squircle button with Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there any way to create a squircle button with tkinter?

A squircle is a square with rounded corners. I was just curious if I can make a squircle button with tkinter..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this in tkinter but there is this one method but it involves an image to do this here is the code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x400')
root.title('hi')

img = PhotoImage(file = 'folder/img.png')
b1 = Button(root, image = img, command = somecommand)
b1.pack()
```

This should work you just have to make an image for the button

Comment: Thanks! It worked but it would've been great if tkinter had an option like that.

Comment: Ya, I know painful to make an image in that shape, but it is the only way